# $\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{lim}} (1-p)^{n-d-1}$, given $p = o(n^{-(d+1)/d})$, and $d \geq 0$ a constant.

Tags: limits, solution-verification, asymptotics, approximation

This is a step in a proof I’m reading. I did a bunch of calculations and it seems like the answer is $1$. But I’m not sure so I’d like to get it checked, or to see a cleaner argument.

Also, my argument relies on the following:
$$p = o(n^{-(d+1)/d}) \Rightarrow \frac{p}{n^{-(d+1)/d}} \to 0 \Rightarrow pn^{1 + (1/d)} = pnn^{(1/d)} \to 0.$$

So as $n \to \infty$, $p$ must tend to $0$ faster than both $n$ and $n^{(1/d)}$ (combined) tend to infinity. Is this a reasonable argument?

Comment: $$
(n - d - 1)\log (1 - p) = (n - d - 1)O(p) = o(1)\frac{{n - d - 1}}{{n^{1 + 1/d} }} = o(1)\frac{1}{{n^{1/d} }}
$$

Comment: I was hesitant to make a statement about the order of $(1-p)$, or $\text{log}(1-p)$. How do we get $\text{log}(1-p) = O(n)$? Also, in the second equality, is the reason we can pass from LHS to RHS similar to what I wrote above: $p \to 0$ faster than $n \to \infty$, so we can have $(n-d-1)O(p) = o(1) (n-d-1)$?

Comment: We see that as $n \to \infty$, $p\to 0$. Thus, by the Taylor series of the $\log$, $\log(1-p)=-p-p^2/2-\cdots =O(p)$. Next since $p=o(n^{-(1+1/d)})$, $O(p)=O(o(n^{-(1+1/d)}))=o(n^{-(1+1/d)})=o(1)n^{-(1+1/d)}$.